# log a user in after authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have the following login mechanism. I am new to laravel. Here after verifying user's data from login form i need to log a user in. To log a user in i need to pass a user to `Auth::login(/...variable..../)` method.

Question is ,it is confusing me what variable should i pass to `Auth::login` method.

I have the following method:

```
public function login(Request $request){

        $data = $request->all();

        $rules = array(
           'username' => 'required',
           'password'=>'required',

        );

        // Create a new validator instance.
        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
        if($validator->fails()){

            $errors=$validator->messages();
            return Redirect::route('user');

        }else{
            if(Auth::attempt(['username'=>$request['username'],'password'=>$request['password']])){
                Auth::login(); // what to pass ?
                return redirect()->route('user.show',[$request['username']]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `Auth::login();`

`Auth::attempt($user_and_password);` is enough as you have done it. It checks those values from db and if they exists the authenticated session will start.

Check the documentation for more information: https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication

Comment: if i don't use Auth::login() , the Auth::user() is null when i try to use it

Comment: @AL-zami what does the Auth::check() method returns after redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest:

```
$user = DB::table('users')->first();
Auth::login($user);
```

By default, this method `Auth::attempt()` will log user, but sometime it not work, you can use the another method such as `Auth::loginUsingId(1);`, read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication)

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel `Auth::login();` is used only if you want to login a user manually and generally you have to pass the **user instance** as a parameter as follow :

```
Auth::login($user);
```

In your case you need only to call to the static method **attempt**

```
if(Auth::attempt(['username'=>$request['username'],'password'=>$request['password']])){
    return redirect()->route('user.show',[$request['username']]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Laravel 5.2

In the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth` you can see `AuthController`. So what you need to do is just make a function name `authenticated`

AuthController

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    \Log::info('message here...');

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```